# How to make a table with dynamic columns in Jaspersoft Studio?

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to make this table in Jaspersoft Studio:

[image: My table]

My table sometimes have one test, two, n test or nothing.
Is it possible? How can I solve this task?

Comment: Looking for the same stuff. Did you find how meanwhile?

Comment: You might want to look into crosstabs

Answer (score 4):

You cannot dynamically create columns in jasper but after creating some fixed number of columns you can hide them using 'print when expression' and 'table component' see the link for more detail [dynamically hide show columns](http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.in/2011/06/ireport-dynamically-hide-show-columns.html)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you still need it but just for the reference. In Jasper Report, you can use 'printWhenExpression' where you can print a particular row/column/value based on a certain condition.
If you know the max no. of columns then add those columns in your design and then hide them using printWhenExpression.
Or else you can also go for DynamicJasper or DynamicReports for this purpose.